# How to inject the request stack into a twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, request

I'm trying to create an extension to render a pagination. It needs the request and the router to be able to create the URL's, so I did this:

services.yml:

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: MyBundle\Twig\MyExtension
    public: false
    calls:
      - [setRequest, [@request_stack]]
      - [setRouter, [@router]]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Then in my extension:

```
private $router;

private $request;

public function setRouter( UrlGeneratorInterface $router )
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function setRequest(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

...

```
public function renderPaginator(\Twig_Environment $twig, $paginator, array $options = array())
{

    if ( 1 == $paginator->getNumPages() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    var_dump($this->request);
    die();
```

Turns out that the var_dump prints null. Although if I do that var_dump in the setRequest method it actually prints a Request object. 
Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When constructing the twig extension, there are no requests in the stack yet, it is empty.

You should delay retrieving the request from the stack to the renderPaginator() method.

Service definition:

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: MyBundle\Twig\MyExtension
    public: false
    arguments: [@request_stack, @router]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Service:

```
public function __construct(RequestStackInterface $requestStack, RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function renderPaginator(\Twig_Environment $twig, $paginator, array $options = array())
{

    if ( 1 == $paginator->getNumPages() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    var_dump($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
    die();
}
```

Comment: I tried but I got the "Call to a member function getCurrentRequest() on a non-object" error. I changed the setRequestStack method and if I do the var_dump($this->requestStack) at the paginator method I got null. I'm using symfony 2.6 btw

Comment: Check the modified service definition. Actually you probably should even do constructor injection instead of setter injection to avoid those kind of problems.

Comment: Mmm no, doesn't work either "Argument 1 passed to SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, none given"

Comment: You must have a syntax issue in your service definition.  Probably too many brackets.  Update your question with the latest service definition.  Make sure your arguments look like what @Gerry shows.

Comment: I double checked, this is my services: `app.twig_extension:
        class: SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension
        public: false
        arguments: [@request_stack, @router]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }` and this my class: `public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $this->router = $router;
    }` I still get the same error @cerad @gerry

Comment: Try to clear cache perhaps. It should work like it is.

Comment: Also, don't call getCurrentRequest() in the __constructor.

Comment: Finally, update your QUESTION with the latest code.  Comment code formatting is less than ideal.

Comment: guys, there's something weird going on here :). I opened a new question, I'm not even able to pass the router, take a look, I don't really understand whats going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676551/impossible-to-pass-the-router-service-to-a-twig-extension-in-symfony-2-6

Comment: Just to confim @Gerry comment, I had similar issues (request object null after a clear cache in dev mode) causing weird behaviours. I removed the calls to `getCurrentRequest()` in my service constructor and now everything is fine.

Comment: Your hint helped me to finally solve issue. I spent about two days to figure what was going on and now it's finally working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this in the symfony google group, problem solved... I had another services.yml causing conflicts. Thank you all for your time
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/symfony2/pRJTYeAYmHE