# Impossible to pass the router service to a twig extension in symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, router

I have a twig extension where I'm trying to inject the router service, so...
services.yml

```
app.twig_extension:
    class: SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Extension:

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

```
class SeoReportExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
```

When I execute the code I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router, none given

Trying to debug this, I did this change in the code to try to understand what's going on:

```
public function __construct($router) {
    var_dump($router);die();
    $this->router = $router; }
```

So I remove the type hint and I do a dump of the object to see what's getting in the construct method. To my surprise, this is the output:

```
Object(Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router)[198]
private 'container' => 
object(appDevDebugProjectContainer)[219]
private 'parameters' => ...
```

So... it actually passes a router object. So... why am I getting the error? I completely lost at this point

--- UPDATE ---
Here's what I found so far:
- In /app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php there are two places where the extension is created:

```
protected function getApp_TwigExtensionService()
    {
        return $this->services['app.twig_extension'] = new \SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension($this->get('router'));
    }
```

Which is correct, it passes the router to the construct
And...

```
protected function getTwigService()
{
    $this->services['twig'] = $instance = new \Twig_Environment($this->get('twig.loader'), array('debug' => true, 'strict_variables' => true, 'exception_controller' => 'twig.controller.exception:showAction', 'form_themes' => array(0 => 'form_div_layout.html.twig'), 'autoescape' => array(0 => 'Symfony\\Bundle\\TwigBundle\\TwigDefaultEscapingStrategy', 1 => 'guess'), 'cache' => (__DIR__.'/twig'), 'charset' => 'UTF-8', 'paths' => array()));

    $instance->addExtension($this->get('app.twig_extension'));
    ...
    $instance->addExtension(new \Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Twig\AsseticExtension($this->get('assetic.asset_factory'), $this->get('templating.name_parser'), true, array(), array(0 => 'SeoReportBundle'), new \Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\DefaultValueSupplier($this)));
    $instance->addExtension(new \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Twig\DoctrineExtension());
    $instance->addExtension(new \SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension());
```

Now, this one doesn't pass the router. But it does pass some dependencies to other extensions. So there has to be a reason why mine extension is not working

Comment: Just for grins, take out the public: false attribute.  You can disregard this as the documentation shows using public: false.

Comment: Done! the problem persists obviously :)

Comment: remove the die(); maybe construct is called a second time without a router.

Comment: @gries you're right! somehow the 2nd time the router is not passed correctly, any idea on why this happens?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have new SeoReportExtension().  Maybe a left over debuging statement.

Comment: Actually if I try to clear the cache I get this: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                              
  Warning: Missing argument 1 for SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension::__construct(), called in /vagrant/www/app/cache/de_/ap_DevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3386 and defined

Comment: try to manually remove all cache files with rm -rf app/cache/*

Comment: You can pass the container to a Twig extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#c-passing-the-container-as-a-dependency-of-your-service

Comment: @thom that is completely against the idea of dependency-injection.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid to pass the whole container. @gries, i tried that as well, when I refresh I got the same error Warning: Missing argument 1 for SeoReportBundle\Twig\SeoReportExtension::__construct(), called in /vagrant/www/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3386 and defined

Comment: @gries not when it comes to twig extensions. Fabien has suggested it himself https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347

Comment: I'd suggest you install a debugger like xdebug and try to find out where the second call comes from - but before that make sure all your caches are really gone

Comment: I found the place, but I don't understand why that code is generated without the injection

Comment: @thom fabien suggested it when you need the templating service. Context matters.

Comment: Interesting.  Does your extension have a getName() method?  Try searching the entire application for SeoReportExtension.

Comment: Yes Cerad, it has a getName method. It returns seo_report_extension. I've searched the entire app for SeoReportExtension and I only founded in the files I already mentioned

Comment: Well.  You have some kind of strange config operation going on.  What I would do is to bring down a fresh Symfony project and just add your twig extension and make sure it loads properly.  Then try to figure out what the difference is.  It almost seems like you have a compiler pass somewhere?  Or maybe two services both referencing your class?  I assume you completely deleted the cache directory when you rebuilt.

Comment: I found the problem... i had two services.yml files with differenct configurations and they were causing the problem. Thank you all for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The Twig environment is available to `\Twig_SimpleFunction` instances as well as `\Twig_SimpleFilter` in the same way, though the Twig docs [only show it for filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#environment-aware-filters).  From the environment, you can get the routing extension like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getFunctions(): array
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_my_link_thing', array($this, 'getMyLinkThing'), array('needs_environment' => true)),
    );
}

/**
 * Get something with a generated link.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMyLinkThing(\Twig_Environment $env): string
{
    $targetUrl = $env->getExtension('routing')->getPath('my_route_name');

    return sprintf('Link is <a href="%s">here</a>!', $targetUrl);
}
```

There are lots of other nifty things in that `$env` - it's worth trying `dump(get_class_methods($env));` and then dumping the results of calling anything in there that strikes your fancy.