# Sylius: Only one incomplete object in RequestStack through particular route

Tags: request, arguments, symfony4, sylius

I am a Symfony beginner and I am writing a plugin for the e-commerce system Sylius: Every route up until now gave me two objects in RequestStack, and I was able to get a very particular variable everywhere through the one I retrieve through $requestStack->getMasterRequest().

In a particular route suddenly the variable (set in yaml file where the routes are configured) is not retrievable and the $requestStack doesn't hold two objects, only one.

I apologize, I know this is very badly explained, I hope someone can make sense of it.

I tried $request =  Request::createFromGlobals() and retrieving the Container instead of the RequestStack directly, but both end up with the same result.

```
# This is the route I am trying to overwrite because I want to give it an extra parameter from the request:

sylius_shop_product_show:
path: /products/{slug}
methods: [GET]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.product:showAction
    _sylius:
        template: "@SyliusShop/Product/show.html.twig"
        repository:
            method: findOneByChannelAndSlug_andVarFromRequest
            arguments:
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.channel').getChannel()"
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.locale').getLocaleCode()"
                - $slug
                - "expr:service('request_stack')"


//This is the function which should be used, it is part of a Repository 
public function findOneByChannelAndSlug_andVarFromRequest(ChannelInterface $channel, string $locale, string $slug, RequestStack $requestStack): ?ProductInterface
{
```

I don't understand why suddenly I cannot get a hold off the variable I can access through all the other routes. Because it is a repository? Is the request not yet completely processed?

Comment: can you describe which objects do you send with reqestStack? Is this something business-logic specific only?

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. RequestStack is a service which I have available through dependency injection. Up until now it was always filled with 2 request-objects, one of which - the one I get through getMasterRequest() - holds the variable I need, but in this case it should isn't. So my question is about how this is possible. And yes, indeed I expect something business logic-like in that variable. It is declared in a yaml-file about routing.

Comment: The configuration above is declared in app/config/_sylius.yaml and I just tried instead of passing the RequestStack directly to the Repository to create a new service and passed it there for processing and the result is still the same. Any other route than sylius_shop_product_show which I extended in _sylius gets the correct value from my new service, but not this.

Comment: Sorry it's /app/config/routes/product.yml not config/_sylius.yaml

Comment: Can it have something to do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672716/how-to-inject-the-request-stack-into-a-twig-extension , answer from Gerry "When constructing the twig extension, there are no requests in the stack yet, it is empty." I have a similar problem, only the situation is different. Or is it?

Comment: What type of variable are you trying to pass ? And how are you passing it ? Is it another GET variable, or are you trying to access something else ?
Passing the entire request stack is effectively a bit overkill and depends on the context, so if we can extract what you need it would be simpler

Comment: Yes, it is counted to the GET variables. I can see that because when I compare the route debugging from a route where it's working, with the one where it's not working I can see it has the same availability like for example "_locale" => "en_US". "_locale" is thus also not available in my extended route sylius_shop_product_show. Does this give you any further idea what it could be by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself yesterday. The problem was that I did not declare the sylius_shop_product_show in the correct scope of the route description which also declared the variable I was trying to pass through, thereby Symfony logically was not able to parse it and make it available. Well, seeing the solution right now it makes perfect sense, but before and the fact that I am a Symfony (and thus Sylius) beginner it was hard to understand what was wrong.

So I understood the problem when I executed php bin/console debug:router which listed all the available routes and when I discovered that the route sylius_shop_product_show actually is not creating a route where the variable I was looking for was even available in the routing-path. Thanks for everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try to enter variable name with `$` symbol before its name. For example if your variable name is `myVar`:

```
sylius_shop_product_show:
path: /products/{slug}
methods: [GET]
defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.product:showAction
    _sylius:
        template: "@SyliusShop/Product/show.html.twig"
        repository:
            method: findOneByChannelAndSlug_andVarFromRequest
            arguments:
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.channel').getChannel()"
                - "expr:service('sylius.context.locale').getLocaleCode()"
                - $slug
                - $myVar
```

How it works under the hood: https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/1.4/src/Bundle/Controller/ParametersParser.php#L55 Note: `$request->get()` method is alias to get variable from GET, POST and Symfony attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved this yesterday, it was a beginner error. But thank you for the resource, I will have a look to learn more.